# Filter array where a property value doesn't exist in another array

Tags: arrays, properties, power-automate

Using Power Automate, I want to filter an array where the values in the OrderNumber property don't exist as an OrderNumber in another array.

It seems like it should be a simple task, but I'm not sure how to handle it. I have unsuccessfully experimented with putting it through an Apply to each action, but the original array has 20,000+ items, so that might not work very well/quickly anyway.

Original Array to be filtered:

```
[
  {
    "OrderNumber": "1234567",
    "CustomerName"" "Customer A"
  }
]
```

Array to check against:

```
[
  {
    "OrderNumber": "1234567",
    "CustomerName"" "Customer A"
  }
]
```

Comment: Your best bet here is to use an Azure Function as it will do it a lot quicker.  Are you paying for PowerAutomate because you'll need a premium connector.

Comment: I do have a paid Power Automate license. What premium connector can I use?

Comment: If you can provide a sample of both arrays, clearly stating which is the array you want to check in and the array you want to check for then I’ll give you an answer.